# ::update() must be compatible with Crud::update()

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

here is my main model that extend from my model:

```
class LoanUserModel extends MY_Model implements Crud
```

I have abstract class something like this

```
    public function update($param)
    {
        // TODO: Implement update() method.
    }
```

and that's my crud:

```
interface Crud
{

    public function select($param);

    public function insert($param);

    public function update($param);

    public function delete($user_id);


}
```

but i have get this error :

> Declaration of LoanUserModel::update() must be compatible with Crud::update()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because your update method does not declare the same type/number of arguments as Crud::update(). Check the original method to see what you have to declare.